# Why does R and PROCESS render different result of a mediation model (one is significant, the other one is not)?

Tags: r, bootstrapping

As a newcomer who just gets started in R, I am confused about the result of the mediation analysis.

My model is simple: IV 'T1Incivi', Mediator 'T1Envied', DV 'T2PSRB'. I ran the same model in SPSS using PROCESS, but the result was insignificant in PROCESS; however, the indirect effect is significant in R. Since I am not that familiar with R, could you please help me to see if there is anything wrong with my code? And tell me why the result is significant in R but not in SPSS？Thanks a bunch!!!

My code in R:

X predict M

```
apath <- lm(T1Envied~T1Incivi, data=dat)
summary(apath)
```

X and M predict Y

```
bpath <- lm(T2PSRB~T1Envied+T1Incivi, data=dat)
summary(bpath)
```

Bootstrapping for indirect effect

```
getindirect <- function(dataset,random){
  d=dataset[random,]
  apath <- lm(T1Envied~T1Incivi, data=d)
  bpath <- lm(T2PSRB~T1Envied+T1Incivi, data=dat)
  indirect <- apath$coefficients["T1Incivi"]*bpath$coefficients["T1Envied"]
  return(indirect)
}
```

```
library(boot)
set.seed(6452234)
Ind1 <- boot(data=dat,
             statistic=getindirect,
             R=5000)

boot.ci(Ind1, 
        conf = .95,
        type = "norm")`*PSRB as outcome*
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function `getindirect` all linear regressions should be based on the freshly shuffled data in `d`.
However there is the line

```
bpath <- lm(T2PSRB~T1Envied+T1Incivi, data=dat)
```

that makes the wrong reference to the variable `dat` which should really not be used within this function. That alone can explain incoherent results.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation! I should be more careful about it.